# How can I disable the 'your formula has an error' pop-up in Excel 2007?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-office-2007

This is driving me absolutely crazy, while I'm in the middle of typing my equations into a cell I like to pre-create the parenthesis sometimes when order of operations is being explicitly set, however if I do =() and then move the cursor back one so it is between the two parenthesis, excel throws a pop up telling me there is an error in my equation, I am not done yet obviously but it's easier for me (as a human) to create the start and end parenthesis first rather than figuring out where the ending ones go once all the starting ones are done. Anyone know how I can turn off this stupid pop-up so I can just write my damn equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to disable it but you can easily work around it.

Just press <kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

The reason it's evaluating the formula and displaying an error is that it thinks the arrow key is to navigate to another cell to include its reference in the formula. What you're wanting to do is navigate within the formula. That's what <kbd>F2</kbd> does. It toggles between cell-to-cell navigation and in-formula navigation.

Comment: ahh cool, thank you very much, if only there was a way to make that the default toggle :)